# How do I spawn a Zombie with Armor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make an adventure map with custom mobs, and I am unsure where to start.  I want to spawn a Zombie with full leather armor and a Stone sword named Lv.1 Zombie.

If you can just give me a layout of the summon command I would really appreciate it.

This is what I have tried so far to try and work it out.

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~3 ~ {CustomName:"Lv.1 Zombie"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to spawn a Giant with equipment?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284306/how-to-spawn-a-giant-with-equipment)

Comment: (Flagging an older question as a duplicate of a newer question because this one has an outdated answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to use the "tuple" `Equipment:` inside the brackets. Example

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{id:minecraft:stone_sword},{id:minecraft:leather_boots},{id:minecraft:leather_leggings},{id:minecraft:leather_chestplate},{id:minecraft:leather_helmet}],CustomNameVisible:1,CustomName:"Zombie"}
```

This will spawn a "Full Leather Set + Stone Sword" zombie.

The `Equipment` tag takes exactly 5 item tags, enclosed by `[]`. The order of these five tags is: hand, boots, pants, chest, helmet. You will have to use `{}` for any empty slots.

You will have to fetch the ID's of the items you want to equip your mob, and place them as members of the Equipment attribute like `{id:ID}`. Each item can also have other tags for things like color or enchantments, and they can be customized using the same logic, such as: `{id:minecraft:leather_leggings,tag:{display:{color:9843760}}}`.

Final note: Starting with 1.9 the `Equipment` tag is split into `HandItems` (main-hand, off-hand) and `ArmorItems` (boots, pants, chest, helmet).

**Further reading:**

- [Mobs for adventure mode](http://web.archive.org/web/20150630215528/http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/maps/1550151-1-7-mobs-for-adventure-maps)
- [Tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20141006182219/https://forums.wynncraft.com/threads/tutorial-how-to-summon-mobs-with-coloured-armor.4993/). How to summon mobs with coloured armor
- [Minecraft ID List](http://www.minecraftinfo.com/idlist.htm)

Answer (score -1):

How to summon zombie armor

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{id:minecraft:stone_sword},{id:minecraft:leather_boots},{id:minecraft:leather_leggings},{id:minecraft:leather_chestplate},{id:minecraft:leather_helmet}],CustomNameVisible:1,CustomName:"Zombie"}
```

Answer (score -3):

Item Summon

```
/summon Item {Item:[Item],Count:[amount]}
```

Jockey summon

```
/summon Skeleton {Riding:{id:Spider}}
```

Mother Jockey

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:minecraft:leather_helmet}],Riding:{id:Spider,Riding:{id:Pig,Riding:{id:Cow,Riding:{id:Slime,Size:5,Riding:{id:Bat,Riding:{id:Chicken,Riding:{id:Creeper,Riding:{id:Zombie,Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:minecraft:leather_helmet}],CustomNameVisible:1,CustomName:"Zombie"}}}}}}}}}
```