# How to spawn a Giant with equipment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I really want to spawn Giant with armor and swords. Because Giants are strong, and great challenge if spawned with enchanted diamond armor and a diamond sword.

Comment: Do you mean that Giant? http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Giant

Comment: Giants won't be much of a challenge at all, even if they have enchanted armour and weapons. They have no AI since 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

All mobs have the `HandItems` and `ArmorItems` tags. The syntax for `HandItems` is this:

```
HandItems:[{<item in mainhand>},{<item in offhand>}]
```

You can provide the id, enchantments, name, etc. Here is the `ArmorItems` syntax:

```
ArmorItems:[{<boots>},{<leggings>},{<chestplate>},{<helmet>}]
```

Like `HandItems`, you can supply enchantments and names and ids. Here's a command that will spawn a Giant zombie with a diamond sword and a full set of diamond armor:

```
/summon Giant ~ ~ ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",Count:1b}],ArmorItems:[{id:minecraft:diamond_boots",Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings",Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet",Count:1b}]}
```

*However*, keep in mind that **Giants have no AI as of 1.8**. The Giant will do nothing but stand there (making it great for a statue). But battle will not work very well without custom AI. I have a supplied a some basic commands that will make the Giant able to be fought.

## Prerequisites

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"AiZombie",Silent:1,HandItems:[{id:minecraft:diamond_sword,Count:1b}],ActiveEffects:[{id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:10000}]}

/summon Giant ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"BattleGiant",HandItems:[{id:minecraft:diamond_sword,Count:1b}],ArmorItems:[{id:minecraft:diamond_boots,Count:1b},{id:minecraft:diamond_leggings,Count:1b},{id:minecraft:diamond_chestplate,Count:1b},{id:minecraft:diamond_helmet,Count:1b}]}

/scoreboard objectives add giantAlive dummy

/scoreboard objectives set @e[type=Zombie,name=AiZombie] giantAlive 1
```

## Run on a Clock

```
/tp @e[type=Giant,name=BattleGiant] @e[type=Zombie,name=AiZombie]

/testfor @e[type=Giant,name=BattleGiant]
```

Hook this one up to a comparator, which is hooked up to a NOT gate, which is hooked up to this next command (this command is *not* on a clock):

```
/scoreboard objectives set @e[type=Zombie,name=AiZombie] giantAlive 0
```

Lastly, this one is repeating:

```
/tp @e[type=Zombie,name=AiZombie,score_giantAlive=0] ~ -64 ~
```

## What does it do?

The Giant will have zombie AI. Killing the Giant will kill the zombie that guides it. The zombie that the Giant obeys (basically it's master) is invisible and silent.

## Giant's Statistics

All Giants have 100 health, half that of an Ender Dragon and equal to an iron golem's.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to spawn a giant with armor and weapons using `/summon`, but I do know another way. First, do:

```
/summon Giant ~ ~ ~
```

Then do:

```
/replaceitem entity @e[type=Giant] slot.armor.head minecraft:diamond_helmet
```

NOTE: you do NOT have to do diamond helmet! And for the sword, it will be:

```
/replaceitem entity @e[type=Giant] slot.weapon minecraft:diamond_sword
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Command:

```
/summon Giant ~0 ~1 ~0 {HandItems:[{Count:1,id:diamond_sword,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:[SwordNameHere],Lore:[[SwordLoreHere][LeaveBlankForNothing]]},ench:[{id:18,lvl:5},{id:20,lvl:2},{id:19,lvl:2},{id:21,lvl:3},{id:70,lvl:1},{id:16,lvl:5},{id:17,lvl:5},{id:34,lvl:3}]}},{Count:1,id:bow,tag:{display:{Name:[BowNameHere],Lore:[[BowLoreHere]]},ench:[{id:50,lvl:1},{id:51,lvl:1},{id:70,lvl:1},{id:48,lvl:5},{id:49,lvl:2},{id:34,lvl:3}]}}],ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:diamond_boots,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:[BootsNameHere],Lore:[[BootsLoreHere]]},ench:[{id:3,lvl:4},{id:8,lvl:3},{id:2,lvl:4},{id:1,lvl:4},{id:9,lvl:2},{id:70,lvl:1},{id:4,lvl:4},{id:0,lvl:4},{id:7,lvl:3},{id:34,lvl:3}]}},{Count:1,id:diamond_leggings,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:[LeggingsNameHere],Lore:[[LeggingsLoreHere]]},ench:[{id:3,lvl:4},{id:1,lvl:4},{id:70,lvl:1},{id:4,lvl:4},{id:0,lvl:4},{id:7,lvl:3},{id:34,lvl:3}]}},{Count:1,id:diamond_chestplate,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:[ChestPlateNameHere],Lore:[[ChestplateLoreHere]]},ench:[{id:3,lvl:4},{id:1,lvl:4},{id:70,lvl:1},{id:4,lvl:4},{id:0,lvl:4},{id:7,lvl:3},{id:34,lvl:3}]}},{Count:1,id:diamond_helmet,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:[HelmetNameHere],Lore:[[HelmetLoreHere]]},ench:[{id:6,lvl:1},{id:3,lvl:4},{id:1,lvl:4},{id:70,lvl:1},{id:4,lvl:4},{id:0,lvl:4},{id:5,lvl:3},{id:7,lvl:3},{id:34,lvl:3}]}}],CustomName:[NameHere],CustomNameVisible:1,HandDropChances:[0.5F,0.5F],ArmorDropChances:[0.5F,0.5F,0.5F,0.5F],PersistenceRequired:1} Where it says things like [[HelmetLoreHere]]
```

Do not include 2 brackets on the name only 1. btw this command is for 1.9+

Answer (score 0):

Use [MCStacker](https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/).
Its really useful for summoning mobs with equipment and status effects.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the SmartGiants plugin to enable a fairly aggressive AI for the Giant.  I use another plugin called Giants to spawn them and I believe one of those two plugins will allow armor or weapons to be added.  I don't spawn them with armor so I've not tested that, sorry.

Comment: The OP probably wants a vanilla solution.