# How to summon a mob with armor in Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[If we can summon mobs with armor via commands in Java](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211966/how-do-i-spawn-a-zombie-with-armor), can we do the same thing in Bedrock Edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `replaceitem`<sup>[Info](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/replaceitem?oldid=1809745)</sup> command.

```
/summon skeleton
/replaceitem entity @e[type=skeleton,r=10,c=1] slot.armor.head 0 diamond_helmet
```

Comment: Never thought of it that way, how smart! I was thinking of using an NBT editor to set a spawner's data. But your method is better.

Comment: I guess doing it 1 by 1 is good enough. No need to be fancy about it.